# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: java, ubuntu-14.04, java-7, rxtx

I have developed Java App for Serial Communication on Windows.I want to run this Java App Jar on Ubuntu 14.04.

Java Version for both Windows and Linux is 1.7 64-bit

Whenever I try to run this Jar on Ubuntu 14.04 I get the below error :

swapnilc@cms:~/Desktop/Janvi/testcode$ java -jar Test.jar

```
Experimental:  JNI_OnLoad called.
Stable Library
=========================================
Native lib Version = RXTX-2.1-7
Java lib Version   = RXTX-2.1-7
RXTX Warning:  Removing stale lock file. /var/lock/LCK..ttyUSB0
Got PortList:: gnu.io.CommPortEnumerator@4fa666bf
Current PortID :: gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier@35a3ae73
Port in Use :: /dev/ttyUSB0
Started
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f30f5b99462, pid=13867, tid=139848257709824
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (7.0_131) (build 1.7.0_131-b00)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (24.131-b00 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Derivative: IcedTea 2.6.9
# Distribution: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, package 7u131-2.6.9-0ubuntu0.14.04.2
# Problematic frame:
# C  [librxtxSerial.so+0x6462]  read_byte_array+0x52
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/swapnilc/Desktop/Janvi/testcode/hs_err_pid13867.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please include
# instructions on how to reproduce the bug and visit:
#   http://icedtea.classpath.org/bugzilla
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
Aborted (core dumped)
```

This runs fine on Windows.

Comment: We don't know the jar... Also the error is telling yu the problem. (Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again)

Comment: @Luftbaum :
The Jar which I am running is "Test.jar". I have copied the native libraries like "RXTXComm.jar" and "librxtxSerial.so" in the respective folders.

Comment: I didn't mean the name xD. I meant the code inside it ^^. Anyway: Try to solve the error message. Enable core dumping.

Comment: I tried this things earlier but still with the same issue.

Comment: Well, somehow you must have failed. I suggest trying again, because it looks like core dumping is the problem

Comment: After trying this once again I get the below error :
...
 Problematic frame:
# C  [librxtxSerial.so+0x6462]  read_byte_array+0x52
#
# "Core dump written. Default location: /home/swapnilc/Desktop/Janvi/testcode/core or core.22749"
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/swapnilc/Desktop/Janvi/testcode/hs_err_pid22749.log
.....

Comment: Then I suggest reading the log file, as it contains detailed information

Comment: Seems like an invocation of librxtxSerial.so through your application fails and therefore causes the error. Please follow the advices given in its [documentation](http://jlog.org/rxtx-lin.html) for Linux platforms

Comment: Note: They even provide a [Linux Installation Wiki](http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Installation_on_Linux) in case you want to compile the sources for your Java version

Comment: Things worked but with 1.7 32 bit.

Comment: Either you use a 32bit JVM or you recompile the lib for 64bit support (if possible). Note, the Java code itself is platform independant and runs on a 32bit as well as on a 64bit environment [without recompiling](http://howtodoinjava.com/core-java/basics/difference-between-32-bit-java-vs-64-bit-java/), any native library though is still platform dependant. So a native library compiled for 32bit JVM support should therefore only be used in 32bit JVMs as far as I'm aware of